# Who were the twelve princes of Gaul?

Tags: historia-regum-britanniae

In Geoffrey of Monmouth's [*Historia Regum Britanniae*](http://books.google.com/books/reader?id=FUoMAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&source=gbs_atb_hover&pg=GBS.PA19), Brutus wanders about western Europe, stopping in, amongst other places, Aquitane and Gaul. He vanquished Goffarius, king of the Pictavians at Aquitane, with the help of Corineus, the leader of the people who will become known as the Cornish. The next passage (page 17) reads,

> The king [Goffarius] after a narrow escape went to several parts of Gaul, to procure succours among such princes as were related or known to him. At that time Gaul was subject to twelve princes, who with equal authority possess the whole country. These receive him courteously, and promise with one consent to expel the foreigners from Aquitane.

Who were the twelve princes?

Comment: Geoffrey's history is largely fictional. I would assume that the number twelve here is mostly symbolical. If Geoffrey gives a timeframe for when this part happened, you can research what the other provinces of Gaul where at that time, besides Aquitaine, and then find the rulers of it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for other historical records for Goffarius being defeated by Brutus, [I found one helpful link](http://folkrealmstudies.weebly.com/brutus-of-troy-first-king-of-britain.html). This explains that no historians have found historical evidence that Brutus was real, however, had he been real, a few math problems can help us figure this out.

If the trojan war happened around 1300 BC, and Aeneas lived during that time. The average lifespan was probably around 70. So if Aeneas was 27 during the Trojan war, so Brutus was most likely in Britain around 1200 or 1150 BC.

I was not able to find anything about 12 princes at this time, but look around that time period, and tell me if you find anything​ interesting.